# sum of two columns in two tables mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i am developing a LMS system for an institute 
and i am trying to develop a recovery report on the end of month
the report contains student name total fee package, total received, total receiveable, current month pending installment

here is the installment data of a student with his admission id
[image]

and this is the ledger data from where ican pick the fee package and total receiveable fees

[image]

and i am using this query for recovery report

```
SELECT 
SUM(l.dr)-SUM(l.cr) as sum_remaining, 
f.dr as fee_package, 
SUM(i.payment) as this_month_install,
a.reg_id, s.fname
FROM
ledger l, ledger f, student_data s, 
admissions a LEFT OUTER JOIN installments i ON a.admissionid = i.admissionid
WHERE 
a.admissionid = '58ac4b5421488' AND
a.reg_id = s.reg_id AND
l.reference = '58ac4b5421488' AND
l.details <> 'registration fee' AND
f.reference = '58ac4b5421488' AND
f.details = 'Fee Package' AND  
i.install_no <> '1' AND 
MONTH(i.pay_date) = '04' AND 
YEAR(i.pay_date) = '2017'
GROUP BY a.admissionid
```

and its giving the result like this

[image]

but the result should be like

sum_remaining = 10000
and this_month_install = 10000
please help me to sort out this problem
Thanks in advance

Comment: Beware of `JOIN` + `GROUP_BY` -- it often leads to inflated `COUNTs` and `SUMs`.

Comment: then what should i do.

Comment: First, understand whether each `JOINs` are many:many or 1:many.  Then try to get each `SUM` with the minimal number of `JOINs`, zero if possible.  This may involve some subqueries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have done this with a sub query
thanks all

```
select  a.admissionid, s.fname, 
sum(l.dr)-SUM(l.cr) as sum_remaining, i.*, 
f.dr as fee_package from student_data s,  
ledger l, ledger f, admissions a 
RIGHT outer join (select admissionid, 
 sum(payment) as this_month_install 
 from 
 installments g where g.install_no <> '1' and MONTH(g.pay_date) = '04' and YEAR(g.pay_date) = '2017' group by g.admissionid) i

ON 
i.admissionid = a.admissionid where a.reg_id = s.reg_id and 
a.status = 'studying' and a.course = 'PH' and 
a.campus = 'CIFSD01' and l.reference = a.admissionid and 
l.details <> 'registration fee' and f.reference = a.admissionid 
and f.details = 'Fee Package' GROUP BY a.std_id
```

Answer (score 1):

you should start from admission and use inner join for the others table (left join for installments)

```
  SELECT 
    SUM(l.dr)-SUM(l.cr) as sum_remaining, 
    f.dr as fee_package, 
    SUM(i.payment) as this_month_install,
    a.reg_id, 
    s.fname
  FROM admissions a
  Inner JOIN ledger f ON f.reference = a.admissionid AND f.details = 'Fee Package' 
  INNER JOIN ledger l  ON l.reference = a.admissionid AND l.details <> 'registration fee'  
  INNER JOIN student_data s ON a.reg_id = s.reg_id
  LEFT  JOIN installments i ON a.admissionid = i.admissionid   AND i.install_no <> '1' 
  WHERE a.admissionid = '58ac4b5421488' 
  AND  MONTH(i.pay_date) = '04' 
  AND  YEAR(i.pay_date) = '2017'
  GROUP BY a.admissionid
```

you have two row in installments table that match  .. try filter just one

```
SELECT 
SUM(l.dr)-SUM(l.cr) as sum_remaining, 
f.dr as fee_package, 
SUM(i.payment) as this_month_install,
a.reg_id, 
s.fname
FROM admissions a
Inner JOIN ledger f ON f.reference = a.admissionid AND f.details = 'Fee Package' 
INNER JOIN ledger l  ON l.reference = a.admissionid AND l.details <> 'registration fee'  
INNER JOIN student_data s ON a.reg_id = s.reg_id
LEFT  JOIN installments i ON a.admissionid = i.admissionid 
                        AND i.install_no not in ( '1', '2') 
WHERE a.admissionid = '58ac4b5421488' 
 AND  MONTH(i.pay_date) = '04' 
AND  YEAR(i.pay_date) = '2017'
GROUP BY a.admissionid
```

Comment: still getting that answer